# Insert two inputs into one column in mySQL with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I am a beginner to php and mySQL and I am currently using dreamweaver for the GUI to help me learn.

I am trying to create a member registration form to register users into database. 
What I aim to do is to have the username be generated from the first and last name of the user. For example: First name: John, Last name: Smith. username will automatically be generated as john.smith (disregarding the capital)

I read about concatenating in php and came up with the code:

```
GetSQLValueString($_POST['firstname'], "text").GetSQLValueString('.'.$_POST['lastname'], "text"),
```

However, when I checked the stored data in mySQL it returns firstname'.lastname. i.e. john'.smith. (Notice the extra apostrophe following the firstname)

This was my source: http://forums.phpfreaks.com/index.php?topic=294444.0, the original poster mentioned that he modified some code that dreamweaver used. But I can't figure out which one to change.

See below for my existing code so far:

```
<?php require_once('../Connections/connSQL.php'); ?>
<?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
$theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
}

$theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

 switch ($theType) {
case "text":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
  break;    
case "long":
case "int":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
  break;
case "double":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
  break;
case "date":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
  break;
case "defined":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
  break;
  }
    return $theValue;
 }
}

  $editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
  $editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}

if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "form1")) {
  $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO member (m_firstname, m_lastname, m_username, m_password, m_workphone, m_address) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['firstname'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['lastname'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['firstname'], "text").GetSQLValueString(' .'.$_POST['lastname'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['password'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['passwordcheck'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['address'], "text"));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want this:

```
GetSQLValueString($_POST['firstname'] . '.' . $_POST['lastname'], "text")
```

Concatenate the values and *then* escape the resulting string, instead of escaping the values first and then trying to concatenate the result.  If you really wanted to escape them first, you could do:

```
sprintf("CONCAT(%s, '.', %s)",
    GetSQLValueString($_POST['firstname'], "text"),
    GetSQLValueString($_POST['lastname'], "text"))
```

But there is no reason to.

Comment: You are a lifesaver. Thank you so much! If I want to use the username, concatenate and add @domain.com to store it as an email what is the script I should use in php?

Comment: @alchuang Any such question can be answered as: concatenate the strings together in PHP and then escape them.  When converting data from one form to another (from a "PHP string" to a "database string") you always do so at the *last possible moment* -- when the data actually moves between layers.